# Storm ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache-storm

I am using Storm for the first time (learning from getting started with storm) and my project fails at runtime with a ClassNotFoundException:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TopologyMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

these are TopologyMain and pom file:

```
import spouts.WordReader;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import bolts.WordCounter;
import bolts.WordNormalizer;


public class TopologyMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //Topology definition
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
    builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer())
        .shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
    builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),1)
        .fieldsGrouping("word-normalizer", new Fields("word"));

    //Configuration
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put("wordsFile", args[0]);
    conf.setDebug(false);
    //Topology run
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("Getting-Started-Toplogie", conf, builder.createTopology());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    cluster.shutdown();
}
}
```

pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>storm.book</groupId>
  <artifactId>Getting-Started</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

```
    <!-- Repository where we can found the storm dependencies  -->
    <repository>
        <id>clojars.org</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
    </repository>
```

```
    <!-- Storm Dependency -->
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

I don't really know a lot about storm and this is for school project so please help

Comment: Fails if you execute it where? Eclipse, console (jar)?

Comment: Please provide the exact command that you give to submit the topology to storm cluster.

Comment: Do you run on local cluster or distributed environment?

Answer (score 7):

you should initiate:

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean install
```

this will create jar files in your target directory.
Afterwards you can use this command to execute the Topology:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue when I ran storm the first time. And the issue was I had to **run TopologyMain class with full package name** like this:

```
storm jar <jar-name> <topologymain class with full package name>
```

[image]

And in case if you find any **classNotFound exception for the dependency class**, then try building **fat jar.**

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong you are creating the jar and then trying to submit it. Probably in your classpath your  `TopologyMain` class is not properly set or may be you need to specify fully qualified path or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass/>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will create a JAR with all dependencies. Make sure you also specify the storm dependency as provided

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>${storm.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I see, the file you show here seems right. You should check the following steps if you haven't solved your problem.

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
storm jar target/your-jar-file.jar storm.book.TopologyMain arg0
```

In the above code, I assume your `$(PWD)` is the root of your project and storm is globally available in your system. This storm executable is not from what you compiled from scratch but the official release.
And your should also know storm executable depends on system's Python, if your OS is Windows, you should check the storm release python script to run your application.